# Autocomplete in String not showing on android studio (Kotlin)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview, youtube

so I follow the tutorial on this page https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=18VcnYN5_LM, and I try to write String on my android studio use Kotlin Programing Language but when I Type String on a tutorial in above I've been stuck, why my String is not showing, I follow the tutorial about Recyclerview in youtube in minutes to 2:14.

this is my MainActivity.kt :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {



override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


} }
```

I use android studio version 3.6.3 on API version 30, this is the screenshot :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because the code in youtube is written in Java and you are using Kotlin.
In kotlin you cannot initialize variables like that.
you have to do something like this.

```
var s1:String = "" 

//in video he is initializing an array so u can use
lateinit var s1: Array<String>
```

I will recommend u to go through kotlin basics first. Thanks